# Problemas ao carregar Dropdownlist em cascata - Asp.net Core MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Tenho dois combobox no qual o segundo possui um carregamento em cascata isto é, quando eu seleciono algo no primeiro, é feita um consulta no banco e os dados devem preencher o segundo... Minha controller parece estar devolvendo um array json corretamente, mas acho que na hora de fazer o loop (bloco JS) não estou conseguindo carregar corretamente o segundo bombobox (id="contatoTipo")... Alguém sabe como me ajudar?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("pessoa-fisica-gerenciar/getContatoTipo")]
public IActionResult getContatoTipo(PessoaFisicaFormaContato pessoaFisicaFormaContato)
{
    var pessoasFisicasFormasContatos = new SelectList(_pessoaFisicaFormaContatoTipoAppService.GetAllByPessoaFisicaContato(pessoaFisicaFormaContato), "Id", "ContatoTipo", 0);
    return Json(new
    {
        data = pessoasFisicasFormasContatos
    });
}
```

DropDowns:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <label asp-for="PessoaFisicaViewModel.PessoasFisicasContatosViewModel[i].PessoaFisicaFormaContatoTipoViewModel.PessoaFisicaFormaContato" class="control-label lb-pessoa-fisica-forma-contato">Forma de Contato</label>
    <select  id="pessoaFisicaFormaContatoTipo" asp-for="PessoaFisicaViewModel.PessoasFisicasContatosViewModel[i].PessoaFisicaFormaContatoTipoViewModel.PessoaFisicaFormaContato" asp-items="@Model.PessoaFisicaViewModel.PessoasFisicasContatosViewModel[i].PessoaFisicaFormaContatoTipoViewModel.FormasContatos" data-plugin="selectpicker" title="Selecione uma opção" class="form-control show-tick show-menu-arrow sel-pessoa-fisica-forma-contato"></select>
    <span asp-validation-for="PessoaFisicaViewModel.PessoasFisicasContatosViewModel[i].PessoaFisicaFormaContatoTipoViewModel.PessoaFisicaFormaContato" class="text-danger val-pessoa-fisica-forma-contato"></span>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <label asp-for="PessoaFisicaViewModel.PessoasFisicasContatosViewModel[i].PessoaFisicaFormaContatoTipoViewModel.ContatoTipo" class="control-label lb-contato-tipo">Tipo de Contato</label>
    <select id="contatoTipo" asp-for="PessoaFisicaViewModel.PessoasFisicasContatosViewModel[i].PessoaFisicaFormaContatoTipoViewModel.ContatoTipo" asp-items="@Model.PessoaFisicaViewModel.PessoasFisicasContatosTipos" data-plugin="selectpicker" title="Selecione uma opção" class="form-control show-tick show-menu-arrow sel-contato-tipo"></select>
    <span asp-validation-for="PessoaFisicaViewModel.PessoasFisicasContatosViewModel[i].PessoaFisicaFormaContatoTipoViewModel.ContatoTipo" class="text-danger val-contato-tipo"></span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#pessoaFisicaFormaContatoTipo").on("change", function () {
            $list = $("#contatoTipo");
            $.ajax({
                url: "/pessoa-fisica-gerenciar/getContatoTipo",
                type: "POST",
                data: { pessoaFisicaFormaContato: $("#pessoaFisicaFormaContatoTipo").val() },
                traditional: true,
                success: function (result) {
                    $list.empty();
                    $.each(result, function (i, item) {
                        $list.append('<option value="' + item["Id"] + '"> ' + item["ContatoTipo"] + ' </option>');
                    });
                    console.log(result);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Something went wrong call the police");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: O retorno não é "value" e "text"? aqui não deveria ser `$list.append('<option value="' + item["value"] + '"> ' + item["text"] + ' </option>');`

Comment: Olá @Barbetta! Tentei fazer conforme sua sugestão, mesmo assim, após carregar, quando eu inspeciono o campo, ele fica assim: <option value="undefined"> undefined </option>

Comment: `item.text` tbm?

Comment: Igual....... :(

Comment: é.. ai tem que debugar rsrs

Comment: Há um problema com o $.each, pois ele está passando uma vez apenas.... ela acaba passando de uma vez e não dá para pegar linha por linha.... Só não sei como ajustar isso @Barbetta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tenta mudar seu `success`:

```
success: function (data) {
            var itens = "<option>Selecione Contato</option>";
            $.each(data, function (i) {
                itens += "<option value= " + data.id + "> " + data.contatoTipo + " </option>";
            });

            $("#contatoTipo").html(itens);
        },
```

http://prntscr.com/mckobi

Comment: Obrigado @Luks Indie :)

Comment: deu certo? só não sei formatar texto ainda nessa plataforma kkk

Comment: kkk Rapaz, eu apanhei...Mas antes de colar os fontes, vc joga no notepadd++ e dá tab em tudo... Se vc der tab em todas as linhas e colar aqui ele entende que tem que selecionar tudo de cinza o fonte... srsrs

Comment: Ok, tive bastante dificuldade com Dropdownlist em cascata, entre outras coisas, não sabia nada de JavaScript, estou aprendendo bastante coisas, esta facilitando muito minha vida no "projetinho" de estudo que estou fazendo (.NET MVC). Precisar de ajuda só chamar, se eu puder ajudar vou ajudar rsrs.

Comment: Valeu @Luks Indie :)